# Mi pregunta esta relacionada con expresiones regulares en Java

Tags: java, regex

mi problema viene con el siguiente codigo:

```
private void _loadInfo(String sFile){

    InfoCategory categoria = null;
    String linea;
    String regex = "^\\[\\d{3}(-\\d{4}){1,2}\\]$"; // [XXX-XXXX] o [XXX-XXXX-XXXX] 
    String codCategoria = null;
    String nomCategoria = null;
    String idCategoria = null;
    String[] cadena = null;
    int cont = 0;

    try{

          f = new FileReader(sFile); // cargamos el fichero
          b = new BufferedReader(f); //leemos el fichero

          //primero hay que detectar que hemos encontrado una categoría

          linea = b.readLine();
          while(linea != null){ // cuerpo principal del autómata

              //hay que ignorar las líneas en blanco
              if(!linea.isEmpty()){ //si la linea NO esta en blanco
                  //aqui procesamos las categorias
                  if(linea.matches(regex)){ // si es una categoria, FALLO, NO SE POR QUÉ NO MTE LA PRIMERA CATEGORIA [018-0001]
                         codCategoria = linea;

                     }else if(linea.contains("name")){  
                         cadena = linea.split("="); // problema: me guarda el espacio incluido, para solucionar en el split poner "= "
                         nomCategoria = cadena[1];

                     }else if(linea.contains("id")){
                         cadena = linea.split("=");
                         idCategoria = cadena[1];
                     }

                  if(codCategoria != null && nomCategoria != null && idCategoria != null){ // significa que ya  tenemos una categoria con todas sus propiedades
                      InfoCategory cat = new InfoCategory(codCategoria,nomCategoria,idCategoria);
                      hCategories.put(codCategoria, cat); // lo metemos en el mapa
                      cont++;
                      // Una vez terminado ponemos todo otra vez a null para "limpiar" los valores de las variables
                      codCategoria = null;
                      nomCategoria = null;
                      idCategoria = null;
                  }

              }


              linea = b.readLine(); //lee la sig linea para procesar

          }
            System.out.println("Hemos metido "+cont+" categorias");                  
          b.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido algun error con el archivo");
    }


}
```

Para que me entendáis, esta función lo que hace es coger un fichero (que posteriormente os pondré como es ese fichero), y meterlo en un mapa cuando haya procesado una categoría (una categoría se considera procesada si se han metido los campos de name,id, y el codigo de la categoria [xxx-xxxx]). El problema es que, en el fichero hay un total de 186 categorías, pero mi programa solo pilla 185 categorías. La categoría que falta me di cuenta cuando depuré el programa. Y resulta que es en la primera iteración de todas(la del bucle while(linea != null)) cuando pilla el primer código de categoría, en concreto, el [018-0001], no se por qué pero NO entra en la condicion del if(linea.matches(regex)), cuando en el resto de codigos de categorías si entra, es decir, en el codigo primero [018-0001] NO ENTRA, pero en el siguiente codigo que es [018-0002] SI entra y asi para el resto. La verdad es que no lo entiendo por que es la primera vez la que falla. En la primera imagen es ahí,con la variable linea a ese valor es donde no entra. Luego en la segunda imagen es el if donde NO ENTRA la primera vez. Y la ultima imagen es la estructura del fichero que estoy leyendo.

[image: Aquí, con la variable linea a ese valor es donde no entra]

[image: En este if es donde NO ENTRA la primera vez]

[image: esta es la estructura del archivo]

Espero haberme explicado bien, y lo que hace la funcion es eso, pillar lineas de texto del fichero y procesarlas como tengo puesto en el codigo. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73149/discussion-on-question-by-user71209-mi-pregunta-esta-relacionada-con-expresiones).

Answer (score -1):

Esta expresión cumple los requisitos que describes en la pregunta

```
^[\[]{1}[\d]{3}(-[\d]{4}){1,2}[\]]{1}$
```

Puedes probarla de manera online con [regexplanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) para ver que cumple los requisitos que quieres, aún así comprueba que no tengas algún carácter de espacio, ya que si no, no cumplirá la expresión, para ello puedes usar la función ['trim'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()).

Comment: Bueno si me quereis poner puntos negativos por algo que funciona bien, haya vosotros.(Así es como después la gente colabora)

Comment: creo que no tiene ningún sentido poner cada término del regex del autor dentro de una clase de caracteres, si como tampoco tiene sentido usar `{1}`... Yo voté -1, no porque funcione o no, sino porque el regex del autor sí funciona, y creo que esto no responde a la pregunta planteada, sino que ofrece un regex menos eficiente aún que el original

Comment: Si ejecutas en regexplanet la expresión regex del autor comprobando los valores [018-0001] y [018-0002], la expresión no funciona.

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgICgwa-PCQw/index.html devuelve que sí coincide

Comment: ... Sin embargo, si te interesa ver más en detalle por qué es innecesario usar clases de caracteres extras en este caso, o repetir una única vez con `{1}` , podrías hacer una pregunta etiquetada [tag:regex] (o más) y con mucho gusto te respondería elaborando más extensamente